# OCR program for IPA?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, ipa, transcription

Is there a program that can convert a scan/image of IPA into any digital encoding?  UTF-8 Unicode preferred, and low-cost preferred (open source would be especially nice).

Comment: Have you tried `tesseract-ocr`?

Comment: (two years later) No, haven't tried it.  Not sure why I never saw a notice of this comment.  No longer doing phonetics, so probably won't try it now.  CISDEM is working extremely well for both Chinese and Latin scripts.